# How to change a color theme for a web app via CSS?

Tags: html, css

I would like the theme of my web app to change automatically depending on a setting.

At the moment, I'm doing it using jQuery like this:

```
if (background == 'dark') {
  $('#graph-container').addClass('graph-dark');
  $('#analyticsbutton').addClass('analyticsbutton-dark');
}
```

However, I wonder if the best practice is to simply create another CSS file with the modified classes and load it depending on the `background` parameter?

Comment: Use LESS/SASS for that. In CSS simply add parent class dependency

Comment: Do you need a solution that might use a bit of jQuery?

Comment: @Code_Ninja can as well be without jQuery or even completely without...

Comment: okay, as I can not visualize how that will change theme of that webapp automatically depending on the setting.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way you can do this is by using the `:root` selector and custom css variables.
The `:root` selector allows you to target the highest-level "parent" element in the DOM, or document tree.

Then, you can simply add a `.dark` class dynamically to change theme.

```css
:root {
  --light-text-color: black;
  --light-bg-color: white;
  --dark-text-color: white;
  --dark-bg-color: black;
}

div{
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  
}

div { 
  color: var(--light-text-color); 
  background: var(--light-bg-color);
  border: 1px solid black;
}

:root .dark { 
  color: var(--dark-text-color); 
  background: var(--dark-bg-color);
}
```

```html
<div>Light Theme</div>


<div class="dark">Dark Theme</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work so well, because some of my elements have different `background-color` setting, so I can't set them in one `:root dark` or is there a way to distinguish between the elements there without replicating the code I already have?

Comment: following your lead I find a better way of doing it is proposed on https://www.sitepoint.com/css-theming-custom-properties-javascript/ where you set up the variables in the `:root` and and `:root[theme='dark']` and then simply switch the theme with the `theme` parameter using Javascript

Comment: @émetteur If you use this approach, that is still going to use jquery/javascript.